# How to always allow Chrome plugins in command line

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to always allow my NPAPI plugin in Chrome. I find in page `"Chrome://plugins"`, there is a checkbox `"Always Allowed"` for each plugin.

Now I want to make one plugin `"Always Allowed"` without clicking that check box, so how can I achieve this? Is there any command arguments for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All, or at least most, Chrome/Chromium command line switches are listed on this page: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/. It is generated from Chromium source and contains links back to the source.

You are probably looking for `--always-authorize-plugins`:

> Prevents Chrome from requiring authorization to run certain widely
>   installed but less commonly used plug-ins.

I have no idea what "certain widely installed" means, but that's the closest thing you have in command line switches. It's entirely possible that your problem is unsolvable because it's a security restriction.

Comment: Great, I tested this and it succeeds! Thx a lot!

Comment: @LeslieWu Can you post the command line statement that you achieved

Comment: @Narayan like this: chrome.exe --always-authorize-plugins about:blank

Comment: --always-authorize-plugin didnt work for me in ubuntu 16.04 in 2 of my 4 computers. I'm loading localhost urls. Until  I added localhost to flash manually in settings, they didnt work. (Using last flash and chromium version for ubuntu)

Comment: The situation changed significantly from 2014. NPAPI is dead, Flash is governed by different mechanisms.

Comment: Ok i got it. --always-autorize-plugins not working when --incognito, removing --incognito flash was loaded

Comment: For anyone looking to run plugins in current day (2024) I have a solution for it.
Download GoogleChromePortablev40 or GoogleChromePortablev42 (I found these two work best with plugins) and then open GoogleChromePortable.ini and paste this line in 

`AdditionalParameters='--start-maximized --always-authorize-plugins --app=http://your-appliance-ip/'`

This will open your browser in a chromeless window (no browser buttons/address bars/interface etc.) and go directly to the address you specify. I use it to connect to an old NVR system that needs a plugin to view.