# Testing on Chrome with flash

Tags: google-chrome, flash, testing

I'm doing automated tests with Chrome.

Part of my suite needs flash to be activated (sight...).

I'm struggling to activate it. Here's what I got:

If I open a regular chrome session, with Flash checked in chrome://plugins, it works there:

[image: Flash checked]

When the tests start, the command line executed is:

```
▶ ps -edf | grep chrome
augustin 24752 24743  2 12:12 pts/0    00:00:07 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/karma-22735678 --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --disable-default-apps --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate --disable-background-timer-throttling http://test.example.com:8080/?id=22735678
```

I always get `Download failed` or sometimes `flash version outdated`.

[image: Download failed]

Even if I check flash in plugins and reload, even if I allow it specifically for this tab and refresh:

[image: Flash allowed]

I tried several command line options:

- `--always-authorize-plugins` from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821375/how-to-always-allow-chrome-plugins-in-command-line)
- `--enable-plugins` from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27210708/disabling-flash-in-chrome)

without sucess. :(

Thanks for the help

---

EDIT:

If I click on + details in chrome://plugins, I can see that in a regular session, Location is set to `/home/augustin/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash/23.0.0.207/libpepflashplayer.so`
, while, in the command-lined open I get: `Location: internal-not-yet-present`

[image: internal-not-yet-present]

This might be the explanation, though I still don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I made it by copying the content of `/home/augustin/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash/*` into `/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash`, `chmod -r +rx /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash` and then adding the following flags to the launcher :

```
    customLaunchers: {
        Chrome_plugins: {
            base: 'Chrome',
            flags: ['--ppapi-flash-path=/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/23.0.0.207/libpepflashplayer.so', '--enable-plugins', '--always-authorize-plugins']
        }
    },
```

Not very plug&play, neither compatible with other laptops, but at least works.

A more robust solution would be welcome!